# How can i load my pdf file from sd card

Tags: android

I have a simple code in which i am reading a `pdf file`from sd card.

Here is my [code](http://pastebin.com/NZ72yTtG)

In the activity `CcActivity: I have given path of the file name,at line number 25:`

`String filename = "/mnt/sdcard/sample3.pdf";`

The pdf is looking fine in emulator.  But now i want to set one button and on click event of that button i want to see all the pdf file stored in sd card. I don't have any idea about it,can some one please help me out to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1** Firstly you have to search all pdf files present in sdcard and store it into an array .
To find pdf files in sdcard go through link [search pdf's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6939479/search-all-pdf-file-present-in-the-android-device).

2 Then show all pdf's from array on any layout you are feasible onclick of button event. After that handle the specific pdf to display in pdfviewer.

Comment: hi! i have try code u have given but when i am calling that function than it shows me force close error.of forse cloase

Comment: hi! http://pastebin.com/HrZR3LRe here is my code on click event of button i am calling walkdir(); method at line num:43...when i click on button it shows me force close error

Comment: Why you are not giving reference to your button and you are not calling method walkdir(File dir) on button click it is not in your code???.