# How to get public storage path? External storage (not SD card)

Tags: java, android, file, storage, public

I would like to get a path to public storage of my android device. I have two applications. One is writing some log files and the other one is used to read them (for this reason I cant use application private storage). I would like to know if there is a method, that will give me path of the "public space" of my device where I can easly create and read files.

This solution is not what I am looking for:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal

Neither is that:

[How to get the internal and external sdcard path in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13361024/how-to-get-the-internal-and-external-sdcard-path-in-android)

Is there a easy solution for my problem?
Is the external public storage what I am looking for?

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal

The problem is that when I run application on my device everything is ok, but then when I run it on device where there is no memory card, it is not working. So I would like to use external public storage, that is not a memory card...

My code below doesn't work (it doesn't save the file). When I choose directory that is directly in Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath(), it work... What I do wrong? :

```
transient private final String DIRECTORY = "/Android/data/com.aaa.bbb.ccc/files/";

public void writeLog()
{
    Calendar calendar = setDate();

    File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + DIRECTORY);
    if(!dir.exists())
        dir.mkdir();

    File file = new File (dir, "log_" + calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR) + "_"
                                 + ((calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH))+1) + "_"
                                 + calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
                                 + ".dta");
```

...

```
}
```

UPDATE:

Why this code works:

```
    File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/Dir1/");
    if(!dir.exists())
        dir.mkdir();
```

And this doesn't

```
    File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/Dir1/Dir2/Dir3/");
    if(!dir.exists())
        dir.mkdir();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try looking at `android.os.Environment` [here.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html)

Following methods seem interesting..

```
public static File getDataDirectory ();
//Gets the Android data directory. 

public static File getDownloadCacheDirectory ();
//Gets the Android download/cache content directory.
```

**EDIT:**
**Solution:**

a small mistake you were making is then

replace this :

```
if(!dir.exists())
    dir.mkdir();
```

with:

```
if(!dir.exists())
    dir.mkdirs(); // will create all the parent directories as well..
```

hope i helped you now
with

Comment: Why that method is not good: getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath and why my code is not working... it should work

Comment: in your code, problem is when there is no SDCard. so i suggested you to find ways to write the file on phone memory. If sdcard is not present how can you write into it?

Comment: The code that I use is to write in phone memory visible as SD card (I have Galaxy S3). The problem is different. When I use DIRECTORY as it is writen now, it doesnt work. But when I put in DIRECTORY only one directory, like DIRECTORY = "/SomeDir/" it works perfectly.... why?

Comment: I just found that mistake in the same moment you posted. But thanks! Let me check if reading is also working

Comment: yeah, nothing can stop you for now!

Comment: on a android 4.4.2 emulator with no sdcard i get permission denied error if i try to write to getDownloadCacheDirectory() EACCESS (Permission denied) when i open a file for writing "/cache/test.tmp". getDataDirectory() is also write protected. on android 2.1 emulator it works.

Answer (score 1):

In some devices the external sdcard default name is showing as `extSdCard` and for others it is `sdcard1`. This code snippet helps to find out that exact path and helps to retrieve the path of external device.

```
String sdpath, sd1path, usbdiskpath, sd0path; 
if (new File("/storage/extSdCard/").exists()) {
    sdpath="/storage/extSdCard/";
    Log.i("Sd Cardext Path", sdpath);
}
if (new File("/storage/sdcard1/").exists()) {
    sd1path="/storage/sdcard1/";
    Log.i("Sd Card1 Path", sd1path);
}
if (new File("/storage/usbcard1/").exists()) {
    usbdiskpath="/storage/usbcard1/";
    Log.i("USB Path", usbdiskpath);
}
if (new File("/storage/sdcard0/").exists()) {
    sd0path="/storage/sdcard0/";
    Log.i("Sd Card0 Path", sd0path);
}
```