# How to get Internal and External SDcard path ?

Tags: android, android-sdcard

I want to open file manager on a button click and want to get the path of a particular item on selection of that particular item.

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13361024/how-to-get-the-internal-and-external-sdcard-path-in-android

Comment: Check this too : http://stackoverflow.com/a/11281048/2269789

Comment: try out this link: https://developers.inkfilepicker.com/docs/android/

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the "files" directory for your app external / internal.

```
    context.getExternalFilesDir(null);
    context.getFilesDir();
```

There's no built in android file picker.  You need an entire module / activity.  You can perhaps get one searching github, like this one [here](https://github.com/Kaloer/Android-File-Picker-Activity) sounds like what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
 File f=new File(Environment.getexternalstoragedirectory());
btn.setonclicklistener(new Onclicklistener){
onClick{  
if(f.isDirectory){

 }else{
//do what u want to do with file 
}}}
```

Answer (score 0):

To get SDCard path....

```
String sdcardPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can ask the user to select a file using the new `Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` intent in KitKat.