# How to get a specific path on the SD card?

Tags: android

I want to access the folder where my app is installed and has it's data, cache etc. How do I do that? I am currently using this but this only specifies a path on the SD card.

```
   File dir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
File FileDirectory = new File(dir, "winrar-x64-560.exenb");
```

Comment: Try to get it through your context, `context.getApplicationInfo().dataDir`

Comment: Check this question https://stackoverflow.com/a/38760040/4564200

Answer (score 1):

You can access this way:

`File file = getExternalFilesDir(null);`

OR, TRY THIS

`File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/Android/data/"+getPackageName());`

Regards.