# How to Adding Restore setting feature by FileinputStream

Tags: java, android, fileinputstream, xposed, xposed-framework

So I am new in programing and i adding a feature in my app which save all sharedpreference key in value in Device internal data folder by using fileoutputStream like this add all data in map and store in jsonobject

```
private String maptojson(){
    Map<String, ?> map = prf.getAll();
    JSONObject object = new JSONObject();
    for (Map.Entry<String,?> entry : map.entrySet()){
        try {
            object.put( entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return object.toString();
}
```

**Now Use FileOutputStream for write file in internal Storage "data'**

```
public void backupSetting() {
    Throwable th;
    FileOutputStream fileOutputStream;
    IOException e;
    FileOutputStream fileOutputStream2 = null;
    File externalStorageDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    if (externalStorageDirectory.exists() && externalStorageDirectory.canWrite()) {
        if (externalStorageDirectory.getUsableSpace() >= 1048576) {
            File file = new File(externalStorageDirectory.toString() + "/data/MyApp/" + "MyAppSetting.ma");
            try {
                new File(file.getParent()).mkdirs();
                file.createNewFile();
                fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
                try {
                    fileOutputStream.write(maptojson().getBytes());
                    fileOutputStream.flush();
                    fileOutputStream.close();
                    if (fileOutputStream != null) {
                        try {
                            fileOutputStream.close();
                        } catch (IOException e2) {
                            e2.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                } catch (IOException e3) {
                    e = e3;
                    try {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        if (fileOutputStream != null) {
                        }
                    } catch (Throwable th2) {
                        th = th2;
                        fileOutputStream2 = fileOutputStream;
                        if (fileOutputStream2 != null) {
                            try {
                                fileOutputStream2.close();
                            } catch (IOException e4) {
                                e4.printStackTrace();
                                throw th;
                            }
                        }
                        throw th;
                    }
                }
            } catch (IOException e5) {
                e = e5;
                fileOutputStream = null;
                e.printStackTrace();
                if (fileOutputStream != null) {
                    try {
                        fileOutputStream.close();
                    } catch (IOException e6) {
                        e6.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            } catch (Throwable th3) {
                th = th3;
                if (fileOutputStream2 != null) {
                }
                try {
                    throw th;
                } catch (Throwable throwable) {
                    throwable.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**Now i want to add restore setting means restore setting by using that file "MyAppSetting.ma". I know i can do it by using `FileInputStream` but I don't understand how to do? please help if you could**

Comment: Are you aware that `externalStorageDirectory` will get you the path to the physical SD-card, not to the shared storage (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/38760040/150978). Additionally be aware that writing to the shared storage as well as to the SD-card requires the app to have appropriate permissions in `AndroidManifest.xml` plus the app have to request those permissions at run-time. In case of the external sd-card you even have to select the path in the file-explorer you grant write access to. Lat but not least direct file access to shared storage only works up to Android 9.

Comment: For Android 10+ you need to use scoped storage. Consider tow rite the data to `/data/local/tmp/` instead. All apps should have write access there (but no read access on the directory so you can't list the files).

Comment: yah i aware about that but externalStorageDirectory work for me now its write my setting file inside internal "data/MyApp/" and my setting file successfully created in that directory but issue is that i want to read that file as a restore setting backup i am working on a xposed module which change device parameters like imei,device,id those identity parameters for give installed apps to spoof parameters and its working properly but now i want to add a feature for save that spoofed parameters and when user want they can restore it if possible could you contribute my project ?

Comment: You men something like this app? https://github.com/BlueCat300/XposedAppSettings

Comment: I fix it by using ObjectOutputStream and ObjectInputStream thanks for help