# How can I look up for all files in an Android device and put them in a list?

Tags: java, android

I looking for help to list all files in Android external storage device. I want to look up in all the folders, including the subfolders for the main folder. Is there a way to this?

I have worked on a basic one, but I still haven't got the desired result. It doesn't work.

Here is my code:

```
File[] files_array;
files_array = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()).listFiles();
```

This method returns 0 size. What is the matter? This is my activity:

```
public class Main extends ListActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        List<File> files = getListFiles(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory());
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<File>(Main.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, files));
        Toast.makeText(this, "" + files.size(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    private List<File> getListFiles(File parentDir) {
        // On first call, parentDir is your sdcard root path
        ArrayList<File> inFiles = new ArrayList<File>(); // Initialize an array list to store file names
        File[] files = parentDir.listFiles(); // List all files in this directory
        for (File file : files) {

            if (file.isDirectory()) { // If the file is a directory
                inFiles.addAll(getListFiles(file)); // *** Call this recursively to get all lower level files ***
            }
        }
        return inFiles;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution found on the web:

```
public void walkdir(File dir) {

    File[] listFile;
    listFile = dir.listFiles();

    if (listFile != null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < listFile.length; i++) {
            if (listFile[i].isDirectory()) {
                walkdir(listFile[i]);
            } else {
                if (listFile[i].getName().toLowerCase().endsWith(".pdf")) {
                    files_list.add(listFile[i]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You actually only need calling the method above with the parent directory that you want to start with. I recommend to put Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() in the parent directory so it will not change with different devices.

Comment: hmm..isn't that answer from the same link that I shared in the answer.

Comment: This isn't much more than a "try this" answer. What is the source?

Answer (score 3):

```
public void Search_Dir(File dir) {
    String pdfPattern = ".pdf";

    Log.d("check",
            "Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()------"
                    + dir.getName());

    File FileList[] = dir.listFiles();
    Log.d("check",
            "filelist length---- "
                    + FileList.length);

    if (FileList != null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < FileList.length; i++) {

            if (FileList[i].isDirectory()) {
                Search_Dir(FileList[i]);
            } else {

                Log.d("check",
                        "for check from .pdf---- "
                                + FileList[i].getName());
                if (FileList[i].getName().endsWith(pdfPattern)) {
                    // here you have that file.
                    pdfArrayList.add(FileList[i].getPath());

                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Where was this copied from?

Answer (score 2):

Conceptually, what you are doing is not complete. Your code only gives you a File for the root level directory. To determine all the files within this directory and the sub directories, you need recursive calls so that all the files are listed to the end of the folder levels.

```
private List<File> getListFiles(File parentDir) {
    // On first call, parentDir is your sdcard root path
    ArrayList<File> inFiles = new ArrayList<File>(); // initialize an array list to store file names
    File[] files = parentDir.listFiles(); // list all files in this directory
    for (File file : files) {
        if (file.isDirectory()) { // if the file is a directory
            inFiles.addAll(getListFiles(file)); // **CALL THIS RECURSIVELY TO GET ALL LOWER LEVEL FILES**
        } 

    }
    return inFiles;
}
```

Now call this function as:

```
getListFiles(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory());
```

Now, you can add your ArrayList as a source to a List Control.

**Bonus**: If you would like to represent list the files in a tree like view, I would recommend you to look at https://code.google.com/p/tree-view-list-android/

Source:
[List all the files from all the folder in a single list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9530921/list-all-the-files-from-all-the-folder-in-a-single-list)

[Search all .pdf file present in the Android device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6939479/search-all-pdf-file-present-in-the-android-device)

Comment: I followed your code but when I use the method above it returns a 0 size. I will edit my code so you have a clear idea about what I‘m talking about.

Comment: @MansourFahad Did you add permission to access the external storage ?

Comment: Yes mate it was there but I don't know why it was fail. Anyway I have solved the problem with the code that I provide as answer. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this: The `java.io` package has been reimplemented within Android. You are able to use the same mechanisms in Android as you do in Java.

```
File fileList = new File("/sdcard"); // Path which you want to read
if (fileList != null) {
    File[] files = fileList.listFiles();
        for (File f : files) {
            // Do something with the files
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does putting the path as "/sdcard" it will access to all files including the files that in subfolders?

Answer (score 0):

I used this code:

```
    private File[] listOfDir;

    /* ... */

    TextView tv = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    listOfDir = show();
    String temp = "";
    if (listOfDir != null) {
        for (File i : listOfDir) {
            temp += i.getName() + '\n';
        }
    } else {
        temp = "null";
    }
    tv.setText(temp);
    ...

    public File[] show() {
        File[] dirs = null;
        File dir = new File( /* Your path */ );
        dirs = dir.listFiles();
        return dirs;
    }
```

And just call *show* to get list all the name.

Comment: What about "your path"? What should I put there so I get access to all files in main folders and subfolders?

Comment: @MansourFahad your path is just your directory path, which you want to see its list of files

Comment: Is there any way to access files that in each path? I mean in the subpath of that path.

Comment: I guess you just need to call `File subpath = new File(*path*+File.seperator()+*name of subpath*)`, it will point that subpath

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help. First you need to fetch the contents of the SD card as shown below:

```
public class FileList extends ListActivity
{
    private File file;
    private List<String> myList;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        myList = new ArrayList<String>();

        String root_sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
        file = new File(root_sd + "/external_sd");
        File list[] = file.listFiles();

        for(int i=0; i< list.length; i++)
        {
            myList.add(list[i].getName());
        }

        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                           this,
                           android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                           myList));
    }
```

Now that you have all the files and folders from your `sdcard` in your `listview`, whenever, you go into a folder, then you need to fetch the contents of that folder as shown below:

```
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id)
{
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

    File temp_file = new File(file, myList.get(position));

    if(!temp_file.isFile())
    {
        file = new File(file, myList.get(position));
        File list[] = file.listFiles();

        myList.clear();

        for(int i=0; i< list.length; i++)
        {
            myList.add(list[i].getName());
        }
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), file.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, myList));
    }
}
```

And again on pressing back you need to load back the contents of your previous folder as shown below:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    String parent = file.getParent().toString();
    file = new File(parent);
    File list[] = file.listFiles();

    myList.clear();

    for(int i=0; i< list.length; i++)
    {
        myList.add(list[i].getName());
    }
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), parent, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                     this,
                     android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                     myList));
```

I think this is what you need.

Comment: That is a good solution but actually I want to list all files not browse through them. Anyway thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a tutorial on this a while ago and still use this from time to time. Have a look; you might find what you need.

[playing-with-sdcard-in-android](http://saiful103a.wordpress.com/2011/09/13/playing-with-sdcard-in-android/)

Try this:

If you don't want the directory to be listed, put files.add(file1[i]); line in the *else* block:

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

    ArrayList<File> files = new ArrayList<File>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        File file[] = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().listFiles();
        recursiveFileFind(file);

        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<File>(MainActivity.this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, files));
        Toast.makeText(this, "" + files.size(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    public void recursiveFileFind(File[] file1) {
        int i = 0;
        String filePath = "";
        if (file1 != null) {
            while (i != file1.length) {
                filePath = file1[i].getAbsolutePath();
                files.add(file1[i]);
                if (file1[i].isDirectory()) {
                    File file[] = file1[i].listFiles();
                    recursiveFileFind(file);
                }
                else{
                }

                i++;
                Log.d(i + "", filePath);
            }
        }
    }

}
```