# Get all non media files in Android 2.3

Tags: android, android-contentresolver

How to get all non media files in android 2.3 ?

```
    ContentResolver cr = getApplicationContext().getContentResolver();
    Uri uri = MediaStore.Files.getContentUri("external");

    String selection = MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MEDIA_TYPE + " = " + MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MEDIA_TYPE_NONE;

    imagecursor = cr.query(uri, null, selection, null, null);

    while (imagecursor.moveToNext()) {
        count++;
    }
```

From the above i am getting all non media files in Android 4.0 and above. But G`etContentUri(external)` is not working in Android 2.3, its showing that its added in API level 11. Is there any alternative to get all non media files in Android 2.3 ?

Comment: Check this: [Get filename and path from uri from mediastore](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3401579/get-filename-and-path-from-uri-from-mediastore?rq=1).

Comment: Try with `Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://media/external/file")`

Comment: @PankajKumar : Its not working in 2.3

Answer (score 0):

As you said, `MediaStore.Files` is only available for API 11+.
So there isn't any method to use `MediaStore` to do this. 
But you have two options to get the non-media files from a device's storage(s).

**1. Iterating through all of the files in the storage:** 
In my opinion **this is not recommended** at all. Because it takes about 15-30 seconds to iterate through all the files. But if you want to do this [check here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18972952/3490833). Then you provide a simple condition to see if it is a non-media file.

**2. Listing all the files once in a database and then get them:** 
This is better than first method. For using it you can check [this open-source application](https://github.com/mohamad-amin/Android-FastSearch/) that exactly does that.