# Install APK from site without downloading

Tags: android, deployment

Until now, I only develop apps for myself or for close friends. 
I don't sell apps so I'm not interested in Google Play.

So, I upload for a personal site I have, give the link to my friends, 
and they download the APK. 
Next they install the app and delete the APK for saving memory space.

How can I install directly my apps from my site without download the APK?

Thank you

Comment: How can you install app from the remote resource directly without downloading?

Comment: As I said, I download the APK and then I run the APK in my phone. Then  the app is installed but I need to delete the APK because after installation is useless and I want to save memory space. If I install an app from Google play, the APK is installed without save the APK in my phone. Is this that I want to know how can I do.

Comment: No you can't auto install apps on phone

Comment: If you want provide some installer (app) when just write it or see existing (if they exist).

Comment: @Cliff, so how the process of installing from Gogle Play works?

Comment: Google Play market is root app that integrates in ROM. Android based on Linux kernel and you cannot install app from another app without root access

Comment: It seems someone dislike my question, so the -1. Probably someone from Google :-)

Comment: For my understanding: You want to remove the downloaded .apk file once it is installed. That file is probably somewhere in `/sdcard/downloads`?

Comment: OMG -2 It seems the the whole Google Play staff is here to downvote.  So, you can do the -3 if you want.

Comment: Interesting post. I know it's old, but I have a similar situation, so I upvoted to get you back to 0 upvotes lol. However, I have clients insead of friends, who are installing the app. Currently, the app is running on a device I supply, but since the application is set as a system app in the firmware, I can't use device storage (as far as I know). I'm hoping I can just load the item into memory, install, then clear the memory. I'm looking into placing updates on a non-personal Google drive, then using Java with the Google drive API to store the file contents into memory. Unsure if possible yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

APK shouldn't be taking that much space but what you can do is this:

1) In your MainActivity, have a method where you [search for APK file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6939479/search-all-pdf-file-present-in-the-android-device?answertab=active#tab-top) in the phone external storage.  (the example searches for ".pdf", change the extension to ".apk")

2) Then use a [APK parser library](https://github.com/caoqianli/apk-parser) to get the package name of the APKs found.

3) If the package name equals to your package name, delete that file.

Make sure to call that method on your `onCreate()` of your main activity.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Google play doesn't use the same method but similar. Google Play is a system app so it doesn't have to have work around like this. It has a lot more permissions. It downloads the APK as a temp file. But this will do the job.

Comment: Thank you Smit Patel, this fits my needs.