# Use a pdf that the user downloads dynamically

Tags: android, android-studio, pdf

So i am doing this project where i need to use PDF files that people download.
For example a user that has the app downloads a random PDF on the internet and then i have to use that pdf in my app, The problem is that i searched and have no idea how to do so.
So the question is how to take a pdf file from the phone storage or google drive works fine too, and use it in an application.

Thank you.

Comment: You can get list of pdf files from storage, have a look on [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6939479/search-all-pdf-file-present-in-the-android-device).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to show a pdf in your app you can do this using webview. This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10861538/5674408) explains it all. Hope it helps.

Comment: I need to use it in order to send it for print, So i basically need to just use the file itself if you know what i meant